# Add Mailbox owner to -AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom Exchange 2010

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

i'm looking to pipe the results of all the users/mailboxes returned from the Get-Mailboxes command, into a Set-Mailbox command which would set the user/owner of that mailbox to the -AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom command, but i'm unable to get this command working so far:

```
Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit "Disabled Accounts" | % {
    Set-Mailbox -Identity $_.identity -AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom $_.alias
}
```

or

```
Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit "Disabled Accounts" | ForEach-Object {
    Set-Mailbox -Identity $_.identity -AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom $_.alias
}
```

Could someone please look at my code and let me know how I would go about fixing it so that the Set-Mailbox command runs successfully, and user name should get added to AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom list of the Mailbox?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: "i'm unable to get this command working" - can you clarify this a bit? Do you see any errors? Are the mailboxes left with a configuration other than what you expect? Please describe exactly _what happens_ and what you _expect_ to happend

Comment: Thanks Mathias. No visual errors are present, even when running a -Verbose command. When I run the command, it appears as though the command runs successfully, but when I view the properties of the mailbox using the Get-Mailbox -Identity "User" | ft *acceptmessagesonlyfrom*, this attribute remains blank even though the command ran without errors.

When running this command, i'm looking for it to take each user/mailbox  its found in the OU, and add those users to their mailboxes' respective AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom attribute

Comment: When I run this command, it works perfectly, but as I need to apply this dynamically to mailboxes in a certain OU, it gets a bit tricky to code:

Set-Mailbox -Identity "Ali Yurkovic" -AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom "Ali Yurkovic"